# Indefinite Generic implies "just one"? Plural Generic implies "more than one"?

Tags: grammar, meaning, articles

**Examples:**

> (1)Fixing a car is a challenge.
>
> (2)Fixing cars is a challenge.
>
> (3)Learning a language is hard.
>
> (4)Learning languages is hard.

---

**How I understand the examples:**

(1) and (3) are called "Indefinite Generic", and (2) and (4) are called "Plural Generic", I believe.

I think Indefinite Generic and Plural Generic are used for talking about something in a general tone.

---

**Questions:**

Question 1:

> Do examples (1) and (3) imply the meaning that fixing "just one car" or learning "just one language" is a challenge or is hard and put little emphasis to cases where there are more than one car or one language?

In other words, do they imply the meaning: "Fixing just one car or learning just one language is hard, but if there are many, I am not sure."?

Does it depend on the context?

Question 2:

> Do examples (2) and (4) imply the meaning that fixing "more than one car" or learning "more than one language" is a challenge or is hard and put little emphasis to cases where only one car or one language is there for fix or learning?

In other words, do they imply the meaning: "Fixing more than one car or learning more than one language is hard, but if there is only one, I am not sure."?

Does it depend on the context?

Comment: Without additional information, you can't distinguish the difficulty level of one or more than one. For example, if fixing one car is a challenge, there is no reason to believe fixing two would be any different.

Comment: Particularly if they're two different cars with completely different systems.

Comment: Generic noun phrases can be singular or plural, [with slightly different meanings](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/000001.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an article used for?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/68792/what-is-an-article-used-for)

Comment: Five years have passed. Such a time. Anyway, what I was asking is whether a Plural Generic and an Indefinite Generic can have a slightly different meaning. For example, can (1) and (2) have different meanings?